# GeoServer/MapFish Print WMTS

Tags: geoserver, printing, wmts

I'm unable to print a [AT-Basemap](https://www.basemap.at/wmts/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml)-Layer with the [GeoServer Print Plugin](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/protocol.html#wmts)

I could not find any working example with WMTS-Sources.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
{
    "baseURL": <your WMTS url>,
    "opacity": 1,
    "singleTile": false,
    "customParams": {},
    "type": "WMTS",
    "layer": <your layer name>,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "requestEncoding": "REST",
    "tileOrigin": [420000, 350000],
    "tileSize": [256, 256],
    "style": "default",
    "formatSuffix": "jpeg",
    "maxExtent": [420000, 30000, 900000, 350000],
    "matrixSet": "21781",
    "zoomOffset": 0,
    "resolutions": [4000, 3750, 3500, 3250, 3000, 2750, 2500, 2250, 2000, 1750, 1500, 1250, 1000, 750, 650, 500, 250, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.5]
}
```

change the other parameters based on your WMTS.